# Placing dynamically an View at the specific coordinates of another View inside ListView item

Tags: android, listview, coordinates

I have 2 views inside listView item. First view is visible and second is invisible. When I click on first view i want to positionate second view at the coordinates of fist view. And when I click on second view second view should  disappear.I used setLayoutParams() , but only leftMargin of second view equals to leftMargin of first, but topMargin is different.

```
private TextView spinnerCircle;`
private ScrollView spinner;`
```

`

```
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
 if (view == null) 
        view = View.inflate(ctx, RESOURCE_LAYOUT, null);

 spinnerCircle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            int[] cirlceLoc = new int[2];
            spinnerCircle.getLocationOnScreen(cirlceLoc);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            layoutParams.leftMargin = cirlceLoc[0] ;
            layoutParams.topMargin = cirlceLoc[1];

            spinner.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        }
    });
    {
}
  return view;
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"
android:id="@+id/store_activity">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ftv"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:id="@+id/store_item_image"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_int_01"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="8dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        android:text="Stress remedy"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/store_item_image"
        android:id="@+id/description_title"
        fontPath="fonts/CaviarDreams.ttf"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:textSize="25sp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/description_title"
        android:text="Stress remedy"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/blue_strip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/store_item_description"
        fontPath="fonts/CaviarDreams.ttf"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/store_item_description"
        android:text="@string/read_more"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/item_read_more_accent"
        android:id="@+id/store_item_read_more"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        fontPath="fonts/CaviarDreams.ttf"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/store_item_description"
        android:text="@string/collapse"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/item_read_more_accent"
        android:id="@+id/store_item_collapse_description"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        fontPath="fonts/CaviarDreams.ttf"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below = "@id/ftv">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/container_store_item"
        android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/blue_strip"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_emptycircle"
            android:id="@+id/spinner_circle"
            android:text="-"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/store_get"

            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:gravity="center"

            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/whitish"
            android:text="Get"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            fontPath="fonts/CaviarDreams.ttf"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/store_get"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/store_item_title"
            android:text="bottle of remedy"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner_circle"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            fontPath="fonts/CaviarDreams.ttf"
            android:textColor="@color/whitish"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/container_store_item"
        android:layout_marginRight="-35dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/store_circle_dim"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/store_circle_dim"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_emptycircle"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="$15"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:id="@+id/item_price"
            android:textColor="@color/blue_strip"
            fontPath="fonts/CaviarDreams_Bold.ttf"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:fillViewport="true"

    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/spinner_linlay">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_0_dropdown_top"
            android:text="-"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:id="@+id/item_empty" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_0_dropdown_middle"
            android:text="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:id="@+id/item1" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_0_dropdown_middle"
            android:text="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:id="@+id/item2" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_0_dropdown_middle"
            android:text="3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:id="@+id/item3" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_0_dropdown_middle"
            android:text="4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:id="@+id/item4"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_0_dropdown_middle"
            android:text="5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:id="@+id/item5"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_0_dropdown_middle"
            android:text="6"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:id="@+id/item6"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_0_dropdown_middle"
            android:text="7"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:id="@+id/item7"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_0_dropdown_middle"
            android:text="8"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:id="@+id/item8"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_0_dropdown_bottom"
            android:text="9"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:id="@+id/item9"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to minus listView scroll offset.

Answer (score 1):

`GetLocationOnScreen` return coord on `screen`.
`layoutparams` is relative to `parentView`.
So it need transfrom.

if U have a `statusbar` and a `actionbar` ,

U should minus them when u get `marginTop`.

Comment: I minus actionbar and titlebar but this happens :
When first view top Margin is 334 second view appears at the same position, but when first view topMargin is biger that 334 second view appears below, and when first view topMargin is lower tha 334 second view appears above first view. And this offset is proportional.

Comment: Can u provide the xml? I make a mistake

Comment: What do u wang to Achieve？

Comment: I want to make something like spinner.

Comment: Why don't you just use a spinner?

Comment: Try to use third-party libirary.